# Jmeter loop through all lines of a CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I've read a lot of questions and answers about the topic, but I'm still confused about the fact that what I want to do is feasible through CSV Data Set Config.

I have a CSV file with many lines representing url, a thread group with 3 users, I would like that in a way or the other if I make a run with 5 loops the result looks like this for the 15 calls:

**url1,url2,url3,url4,...,url15**

Is it feasible?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. Given you have `test.csv` file which is located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and having content like:

   ```
   http://example.com/url1
   http://example.com/url2
   http://example.com/url3
   ...
   http://example.com/url15
   ```
2. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
3. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to the Thread Group and configure it like:

   [image]
4. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to the Thread Group and put `${url}` to the "Path" field. You may also want to amend sampler name to look like:

   ```
   User: ${__threadNum}, Iteraion: ${__jm__Thread Group__idx}, URL: ${url}
   ```

   this way you will be able to see mapping of URL from CSV with the current ID of the virtual user and loop of the Thread Group

   [image]
5. That's it, now you can add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to visualize sampler label, request and response details and run your test - it will generate 15 requests which will be sequentially taken from the CSV file:

   [image]